# How to add date and time to table in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime

I need to add column with date and time from excel to postgresql
it looks like that:

| Column A |
| --- |
| 12.05.21 18:54 |
| 13.05.21 13:34 |

when I try to add it in sql, like that:

> insert into lst (created_at) values
> (12.05.21 18:54),
> (13.05.21 13:34)
> an error occurs:
> ERROR:  syntax error (approximate position: ".21")
> LINE 2:  (12.05.21 18:54),

how is right to add date and time in table?

Comment: `select '12.05.21 18:54'::timestamp; 2021-12-05 18:54:00`. So single quote the values.

Comment: See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-populate.html

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code by adding single quotes to the date and time values.

```
INSERT INTO lst (created_at)
VALUES
  ('2021-05-12 18:54'),
  ('2021-05-13 13:34');
```